# How to embed a link in a custom component as a slot?

Tags: javascript, shadow-dom, custom-component, custom-element, createelement

I'm trying to create a simple component which contains some animation. I have the name attrib set for the link's text. I have a slot set up for the destination of the link, but the template is not allowing the link to be set as a slot. I'm not sure what to try next.

When I hover on the link, it just says `<slot name=` instead of the actual URL.

```js
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `
  <style>
    .txt-link a {
      color: #005fec;
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 18px;
      text-decoration: none;
      position: relative;
    }
    .txt-link a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .txt-link a::before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -5px;
      left: 0;
      width: 0;
      height: 1px;
      background-color: #005fec;
      visibility: hidden;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    }
    .txt-link a:hover::before {
      visibility: visible;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .txt-link.arrow-link img {
      height: 15px;
      position: relative;
      top: 2px;
    }
  </style>
  <div class="txt-link arrow-link">
    <a href="<slot name="destination" />"></a>
    <img alt="arrow right icon" class="learn-more-arrow" src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/73-734729_arrow-blue-right-transparent-blue-arrow-right-clipart.png" loading="lazy">
  </div>
`;

class CustomAnimLink extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.showInfo = true;

    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    this.shadowRoot.querySelector('a').innerText = this.getAttribute('name');
  }
}

window.customElements.define('custom-anim-link', CustomAnimLink);
```

```html
<custom-anim-link name="Learn more">
  <div slot="destination">https://www.yahoo.com</div>
</custom-anim-link>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with slots. Slots are used to place `HTMLElement`s in the place of the slot and can't be used for anything other than that.

Instead pass the URL as an attribute. That seems appropriate for the data type. Web Components has some nice life cycles to help you with this.

I've added `static get observedAttributes()` to indicate that some attributes should be observed. Doing this will enable you to do something whenever the value in one of the attributes is changed, like updating the URL on the anchor in the Shadow DOM.

Whenever an observed attribute value changes the `attributeChangedCallback` is called in which you can determine what should happen whenever a value changes.

Both the `observedAttributes` and `attributeChangedCallback` are part of Web Component life cycle hooks.

```js
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `
  <style>
    .txt-link a {
      color: #005fec;
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 18px;
      text-decoration: none;
      position: relative;
    }
    .txt-link a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .txt-link a::before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -5px;
      left: 0;
      width: 0;
      height: 1px;
      background-color: #005fec;
      visibility: hidden;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    }
    .txt-link a:hover::before {
      visibility: visible;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .txt-link.arrow-link img {
      height: 15px;
      position: relative;
      top: 2px;
    }
  </style>
  <div class="txt-link arrow-link">
    <a href=""><slot></slot></a>
    <img alt="arrow right icon" class="learn-more-arrow" src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/73-734729_arrow-blue-right-transparent-blue-arrow-right-clipart.png" loading="lazy">
  </div>
`;

class CustomAnimLink extends HTMLElement {

  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['name', 'destination'];
  }

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.showInfo = true;
    this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }

  get anchor() {
    return this.shadowRoot.querySelector('a');
  }

  get name() {
    return this.getAttribute('name');
  }

  set name(value) {
    if ('string' === typeof value) {
      this.setAttribute('name', value);
    }
  }

  get destination() {
    return this.getAttribute('destination');
  }

  set destination(value) {
    if ('string' === typeof value) {
      this.setAttribute('destination', value);
    }
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(attrName, oldValue, newValue) {
    switch (attrName) {
      case 'destination':
        this.anchor.href = newValue;
        break;
      case 'name':
        this.anchor.textContent = newValue;
        break;
    }
  }
}

window.customElements.define('custom-anim-link', CustomAnimLink);
```

```html
<custom-anim-link name="Learn more" destination="https://www.yahoo.com"></custom-anim-link>
```

Alternatively, you could pass the `<a>` tag in the place for the slot. Then get all elements assigned to the `destination` slot and set the `textContent` properties based on the value of the `name` attribute. Same goes for the `destination` attribute we've added in the last example.

```js
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `
  <style>
    .txt-link a {
      color: #005fec;
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 18px;
      text-decoration: none;
      position: relative;
    }
    .txt-link a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .txt-link a::before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -5px;
      left: 0;
      width: 0;
      height: 1px;
      background-color: #005fec;
      visibility: hidden;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    }
    .txt-link a:hover::before {
      visibility: visible;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .txt-link.arrow-link img {
      height: 15px;
      position: relative;
      top: 2px;
    }
  </style>
  <div class="txt-link arrow-link">
    <slot name="destination"></slot>
    <img alt="arrow right icon" class="learn-more-arrow" src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/73-734729_arrow-blue-right-transparent-blue-arrow-right-clipart.png" loading="lazy">
  </div>
`;

class CustomAnimLink extends HTMLElement {

  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['name', 'destination'];
  }

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.showInfo = true;
    this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }

  get destinations() {
    const slot = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('slot');
    const assignedElements = slot.assignedElements();
    return assignedElements;
  }

  get name() {
    return this.getAttribute('name');
  }

  set name(value) {
    if ('string' === typeof value) {
      this.setAttribute('name', value);
    }
  }
  
  get destination() {
    return this.getAttribute('destination');
  }

  set destination(value) {
    if ('string' === typeof value) {
      this.setAttribute('destination', value);
    }
  }
  
  attributeChangedCallback(attrName, oldValue, newValue) {
    switch(attrName) {
      case 'name':
        this.destinations.forEach(destination => {
          destination.textContent = newValue;
        });
        
        break;
      case 'destination':
        this.destinations.forEach(destination => {
          destination.href = newValue;
        });
        
        break;
    }
  }
}

window.customElements.define('custom-anim-link', CustomAnimLink);
```

```html
<custom-anim-link name="Learn more" destination="https://www.yahoo.com">
  <a slot="destination"></a>
</custom-anim-link>
```

Or as a last simple resort, just pass the `<a>` in it's entirety as child to your custom element.

```
<custom-anim-link>
  <a href="https://www.yahoo.com">Learn more</a>
</custom-anim-link>
```

Comment: Looks like I still have more to learn. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to set the href of an a-tag in a web component when its created, its a lot easier with a data tag:

```js
class CustomAnimLink extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.showInfo = true;

    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });

    let template = document.getElementById("github-link-template");
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));

    this.shadowRoot.querySelector('a').href= this.dataset.href;
  }
}

window.customElements.define('custom-anim-link', CustomAnimLink);
```

and then

```html
<custom-anim-link data-href="https://www.yahoo.com"></custom-anim-link>
```

For the actual content of the a-tag ("Learn more"), you should be able to use a slot without problems.